# Segementing a recursive tree in haskell

Tags: html, haskell, recursion

Could somebody help me work out how to abstract the recursion from this code for me please?
I'm trying to write something that takes a pandoc structure, and subdivides the tree
whenever it finds a sentence, so:

```
<span>This sentence. Should split.</span>
```

becomes:

```
<span>
  <span { sentence }>This sentence.</span>
  <span { sentence }> Should split.</span>
</span>
```

I have a working implementation, but the recursive part is a bit repetitive:

```
segment :: [Inline] -> [Inline]
segment [] = []
segment [el] = [el]
segment els @ (head:tail) =
  case head of
    Emph ch -> map (Emph . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Strong ch -> map (Strong . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Strikeout ch -> map (Strikeout . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Superscript ch -> map (Superscript . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Subscript ch -> map (Subscript . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    SmallCaps ch -> map (SmallCaps. toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Quoted qt ch -> map (Quoted qt . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Cite cs ch -> map (Cite cs . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    Span attr ch -> map (Span attr . toList) (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    _ ->
      maybe [sentence els] (\i -> (sentence $ take i els) : segment (drop i els))
        $ (1 +) <$> List.findIndex split els
  where
    sentence = Span ("sentence", [], [])

split :: Inline -> Bool
split (Str str) = endsWith "." str || endsWith "?" str || endsWith "!" str
split _         = False

endsWith :: String -> String -> Bool
endsWith suff str = suff `List.isSuffixOf` str

toList :: a -> [a]
toList = (: [])
```

I'm trying to work out a way to hand in some `f` that will model the part that splits the structure
(i.e the bottom bit), but I'm struggling as the function has to be `[Inline] -> [Inline]`, it's also
as if it needs to be `Inline -> [Inline] -> [Inline]` as each of the recursive steps need the original
constructor in order to preserve the structure of the document, ie:

```
<span><strong>This sentence. Should split.</strong></span>
```

becomes:

```
<span>
  <strong><span { sentence }>This sentence.</span></strong>
  <strong><span { sentence }> Should split.</span></strong>
</span>
```

Comment: You can probably avoid any manual recursion by using `walk` from `Text.Pandoc.Walk` (in package `pandoc-types`).

Comment: That one walks into the `Image` and `Link` constructors, which are omitted here. One of `transformOf (each . inlinePrePlate)`  and `transformOf (inlinePrePlate . each)` could do that job, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pandoc-lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-lens-0.6.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Lens.html#v:-36-fPlatedInline) provides a matching `Plated` instance for `Inline`, but we want to modify the number of `Inline`s to one, so we'll need an `inlinePrePlate :: Traversal' Inline [Inline]`. Let's [submit that](https://github.com/bgamari/pandoc-lens/pull/5). Usually `template` could have done our job,
 but we don't want to target the `[Inline]` arguments of the `Link` and `Image` constructors.

```
segment :: [Inline] -> [Inline]
segment [] = []
segment [el] = [el]
segment els @ (head:tail) = if has inlinePrePlate head
  then traverseOf inlinePrePlate (map (\x -> [x]) . segment) head ++ segment tail
  else case break1 split els of
    (sent, segs) -> Span ("sentence", [], []) sent : segment segs

break1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
break1 f [] = ([], [])
break1 f (x:xs) | f x = ([x], xs)
break1 f (x:xs) = let (y,ys) = break1 f xs in (x:y,ys)
```

(I don't understand the part of your post that talks about an `f`.)

`segment [el] = [el]` is superfluous, right?

No sentence contains anything that has children, right?

It appears that to me that

```
<span>This sentence. Should split.</span>
```

instead becomes:

```
<span> <span { sentence }>This sentence.</span> </span>
<span> <span { sentence }> Should split.</span> </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with something unrelated to recursion: A first cleanup step might be to reduce the repetition in `segment`:

```
segment els @ (head:tail) =
  let constr = case head of
                 Emph ch        -> Just (Emph, ch)
                 Strong ch      -> Just (Strong, ch)
                 Strikeout ch   -> Just (Strikeout, ch)
                 Superscript ch -> Just (Superscript, ch)
                 Subscript ch   -> Just (Subscript, ch)
                 SmallCaps ch   -> Just (SmallCaps, ch)
                 Quoted qt ch   -> Just (Quoted qt, ch)
                 Cite cs ch     -> Just (Cite cs, ch)
                 Span attr ch   -> Just (Span attr, ch)
                 _              -> Nothing
      sentence = Span ("", ["sentence"], [])
  in case constr of
    Just (inlnConstr, ch) -> map inlnConstr (segment ch) ++ segment tail
    _               ->
      maybe [sentence els] (\i -> (sentence $ take i els) : segment (drop i els))
        $ (1 +) <$> List.findIndex split els
```

Note that we not only cut away the repeating `(segment ch)` and `++ segment tail`, but also the `toList`, which is just an `id` here (as the result of `segment` already is a List.

Next would be the splitting, which could be done using `break` instead of `findIndex`, `drop`, and `take`:

```
      case break split els of
        (_, [])    -> [sentence els]
        (xs, y:ys) -> sentence (xs ++ [y]) : segment ys
```

The last part of your post might better be asked on stackoverflow, as there is no working code for this yet.

Comment: `ch` is not in scope by the time of its use.

Comment: To be fair you can then have `constr` be `Maybe ([Inline] -> Inline, [Inline])` and have it return `Just (Constructor, ch)`, at least that then separates the repetition in the recursive part. Still doesn't feel that elegant though.

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now. (Getting a good code review on one's code review is actually quite awesome).

Comment: `toList` is not `id` as OP defines it as `(:[])`.